# unable to write to mongodb from visual studio

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio

I just started coding, I decided to build a web app with visual studio and mongodb.

I installed the mongodb driver from visual studio and locally installed mongodb in the default mongodb location. I created the first initial page to create the first user and created a class for mongodb collection, however, every time I submit the information of the user nothing happens, no error messages that I can see, it seems as if everything resolves fine, but when I go to the DB, the collection and first doc. that were supposed to be created are not there, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

this is the frontend code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project1.Pages.CreateUser" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/common.css" />
<title>Create User</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img src="../Images/JotNotes.png" />
        <p>NEW USER NAME:    
            <input type="text" name="UserName" id="txNewUserName"     runat="server" /></p>
        <p>NEW PASSWORD:
            <input type="password" name="NewPassword" id="txPassword" runat="server" /></p>
        <p>CONFIRM PASSWORD:
            <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" /></p>
        <p>FIRST NAME:    
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="txFirstName" runat="server" /></p>
        <p>LAST NAME:    
            <input type="text" name="LastName" id="txLastName" runat="server" /></p>
        <p>E-MAIL ADDRESS:    
            <input type="text" name="eMail" id="txEmailAddress" runat="server" /></p>
        <p>
            <button class="mainButton" onclick="CreateUserName" value="CREATE USER" id="btCreateUser" runat="server" /></p>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Project1.Pages
{
public partial class CreateUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void CreateUserName(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Projectdb");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<User>("User");
        User user = new Project1.User();
        user.userName = txNewUserName.Value;
        user.password = txPassword.Value;
        user.firstName = txFirstName.Value;
        user.lastName = txLastName.Value;
        user.eMail = txEmailAddress.Value;

        //validation if user exist

        coll.InsertOneAsync(user);
    }
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are instantiating `mongoclient` you are not passing the database location path.

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb//localhost:27017");
```

Next use `BsonDocument` as a collection type.

```
var db = client.GetDatabase("Projectdb");
var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("User");
```

Construct the object of user of type `BsonDocument`.Left side key indicates column name and right side key indicates value to be inserted.

```
var user = new BsonDocument{
{userName,txNewUserName.Value},
{password,txPassword.Value},
..
{eMail,txEmailAddress.Value}
};

coll.InsertOneAsync(user);
```

Check in mongo console by using below commands.

```
use Projectdb
db.user.find()
```

Comment: Thanks Navoneel, this seems to be the right answer to the problem, however, I'm getting an error message now on the table names saying that "The name "%%" does not exist in the current context" the solutions that visual studio are offering are not really helpful.

Comment: this what the right answer, the column names just had to be passed as strings. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the mongodb server?

Comment: hi Kraken, I have started the mongodb server, I can see the instance running via Robomongo and nothing gets updated